# Parsing and XML product feed

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML product feed that I am parsing with `PHP` to load products into a `database.`

I need to get each element into an array of `$products = array()` such as:

```
$products[AttributeID] = value
```

This is what I have so far:

I am using simplexml and I have got most of it:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($CatalogFileName) or die("can't open file " . $CatalogFileName);

    foreach($xml->children() as $products) { 
        foreach($products->children() as $product) {
            $new_product = array();
            $new_product[sku] = "AS-" . $product->Name;
            foreach($product->Values->Value as $node) { 
                $node_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $node[AttributeID]);
                $new_product[$node_name] = $node[0];  <--THIS IS NOT WORKING: $node[0] returns an array I only want the data in each attribute.
            }
            foreach($product->AssetCrossReference as $node) { 
                $new_product[image] = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/images/items/fullsize/" . $node[AssetID] . ".jpg";
            }
            print_r($new_product); 
        }
    }
```

Here is an image of one product node: [XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3v3W.jpg)

Can someone provide me with a little help here?  I do a lot of PHP programming but this is the first time I am dealing with XML

Comment: You can for example use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [DOMDocument.loadXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) and [DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( "<your-xml/>" );

$products = [];
foreach ( $doc->getElementsByTagName( "Product" ) as $el ) {
    $p = handleProduct( $el );   
    $products[ $p->id ] = $p;
}

function handleProduct( DOMElement $el ) {
   return (object) [
       "ID" => $el->getAttribute( "ID" ),
       ....
   ];
}
```